# Minecraft new 1.14.2 tag display name detection command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a command to switch between cameras using the `testfor` command to identify which camera the player is holding. My "cameras" are items with custom names 1,2,3,4, etc.

This is the code i am using:

```
/execute if entity @a[team=camera,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:black_stained_glass_pane",tag:{display:{Name:"camera 1"}}}}]
```

The code does not detect the renamed item. It detects if I remove the name, but I require the custom name for my project.

I've also tried this thing as said in other people´s question.

```
{Name:\"camera 1\"}}
```

But it does not work - the code turns red. I'm not sure what is wrong or how to fix it. I'm running Minecraft 1.14.2 Java edition.

Comment: Can you complete your command by adding a `run` clause?  For example, `/execute ... run say foo`.  This helps future readers.

Comment: can't test it on this Pc, but try to escape the name part.. like `tag:{display:{Name:\"camera 1\"}}`

Comment: it did not work neither of those , the code gets red if i add {Name:\"camera 1\"}} and it does not change a single thing if i add run...

Comment: @D3T0NA It needs to be `{Name:"\"camera 1\""}` as explained in the answer to the other question.